# When RFID tag is removed

Tags: programming

After rewriting and getting a good grip on what I have got in my sketch so far, I need some assistance.

So in my sketch I can play an MP3 track with a certain tag, but when that tag is removed I can't  start the fading out process.

So for all that helped on previous ones, where I just mashed a lot of code together and hoped for the best, this one should start to have some good foundations to build on.

But I'm stuck on the part that's commented out.

//rfid

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define RST_PIN         9  // reset pin 9
#define SS_PIN          10 // sda pin 10
MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create MFRC522 instance

// = 0001.mp3    8C DE 63 A9   uid's for me to relate to mp3 tracks.
// = 0002.mp3    0A 97 F3 16 /
// = 0003.mp3    3A 5F DE 16

//mp3 player
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
int mp3Pin[2] = { 5, 4 }; //Rx/Rx

// For the checksum to the mp3
#define startByte 0x7E
#define endByte 0xEF
#define versionByte 0xFF
#define dataLength 0x06
#define infoReq 0x01

SoftwareSerial mp3(mp3Pin[0], mp3Pin[1]); // Rx, Tx

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522
  rfid.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial(); // Print version of RFID

  //Mp3
  mp3.begin(9600); // Init mp3
  delay(1000);
  sendMP3Command(0x3F, 0, 0); // Send request for initialization parameters
  sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 20); // Vol set to 30
  sendMP3Command(0x07, 0, 0); // EQ = pop
}

void loop() {
  // Look for new cards
  if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    //In new card found and new serial
    /*printHex(rfid.uid.uidByte, rfid.uid.size); // Print the Hex uid &
      Serial.println(); // use to get new uids.*/
    {
      String content = "";
      byte letter;
      for (byte i = 0; i < rfid.uid.size; i++) {
        content.concat(String(rfid.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
        content.concat(String(rfid.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
      }
      content.toUpperCase();
      if (content.substring(1) == "0A 97 F3 16") {
        //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
        //Serial.println("hello World");
        Serial.println("0002.mp3");
        sendMP3Command(0x03, 0, 0002); // Play track 0002.mp3
        sendMP3Command(0x19, 0, 0); // Loop track playing
        delay(30);
      }
      /*else !rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent();{
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 28); // Reduce vol by 2 and fade out
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 26);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 24);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 22);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 20);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 18);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 16);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 14);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 12);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 10);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 8);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 6);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 4);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 2);
        delay(30);
        sendMP3Command(0x06, 0, 0);
        //sendMP3Command(0x16, 0, 0); // Stop
        delay(500); // Change value if you want to read cards faster
        }*/
    }
    // Halt PICC
    rfid.PICC_HaltA();
    // Stop encryption on PCD
    rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();
  }
}

void sendMP3Command(byte Command, byte Param1, byte Param2) {
  // Calculate the checksum
  unsigned int checkSum = -(versionByte + dataLength + Command + infoReq + Param1 + Param2);
  // Construct the command line
  byte commandBuffer[10] = { startByte, versionByte, dataLength, Command, infoReq, Param1, Param2, highByte(checkSum), lowByte(checkSum), endByte };
  for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 10; cnt++) {
    mp3.write(commandBuffer[cnt]);
  } // Delay needed between successive commands delay(30); }
  /*   // Print the Hex uid & use to get new uids.
    void printHex(byte * buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
      Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
      Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
    }*/
```

Comment: how is it that you write several `for` loops and then you write linear code like that commented out code?

Comment: Which RFID reader? Which Arduino? Using "programming" as a tag is rather generic. Obviously it is programming.

Comment: In general, RFID readers send a message when a card is presented. They don't send a message when a card is moved out of range. Unless you have a fancy reader that tells you that (and in that case it would help to mention the reader type).

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. Sorry, a mfrc522 reader coupled with a nano and a dfplayer MP3. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have written this code:

```
void loop() 
{
  // Look for new cards
  if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    {
      // ...
      if (content.substring(1) == "0A 97 F3 16") 
      {
        // play
      } else
      {
        // stop
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Try something like this:

```
bool playing = false;

void loop() 
{
  // Look for new cards
  if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    // ...
    if (content.substring(1) == "0A 97 F3 16") 
    {
      // play
      playing = true;
    }
    // ... 
  }
  if (playing && !anyCardPresent())
  {
    // stop
    playing = false;
  }
}
```

and for the implementation od anyCardPresent refer to this [discussion](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/issues/188) - if more consecutive calls of PICC_ReadCardSerial fail, you can consider this as card being removed

Comment: Thank you gabonator, I will try this when I'm home. I did use some code that could tell when the card was removed but the person who wrote it and myself didn't really understand it or how it worked. I can post it later if that might help. Regards